# FirefoxOS device manifest

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I'm trying to port FirefoxOS on Motorola G but I don't understand how to write device manifest. What should be specified in the manifest? Where do I start? Mozilla's official documentation isn't that helpful actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manifest is tricky but like a bike - one you get the hang of it then it becomes second-nature.

Here are the links I used to understand the manifest:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/Manifest
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/About_app_manifests?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FApps%2FFAQs%2FAbout_app_manifests

The main point that helped me was to understand that only two fields are required: name, and description. This make other options specific to your needs, so I stripped all other members out to start: "locales" and "developer".

The primary config that I needed to get right was:
launch_path - I got it to work through trial-and-error, but then moved the app within my architecture and was surprised when the app went 404! I shouldn't have been surprised because... the path was incorrect. After updating the path the app installed correctly.

For example: 
/Apps/App1/app1.html

Final bit of advice on Manifest. The best way to understand it is to get a test app working from the mdn-app-template! This way you can see how it works and test it's capabilities. **I strongly recommend this as a first step**. https://github.com/chrisdavidmills/mdn-app-template

Other suggestions:
- It took a while to get the workflow down. It is possible to just click a 'refresh' link in the App Manager. Which is a rather immediate workflow.
- Uninstalling in Android was weird. The app is actually saved within Firefox. So you have to go to about:apps to uninstall. Here is the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/Apps_for_Android

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I accept the answer without reading it well after someone helped me. Actually it's not app manifest but repository manifest, for repo command to download right source code from different source, like github and similar. My fault.